# Environment.TickCount never resets on my machine, why?

Tags: .net, system

According to the documentation, [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) returns "*the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started*".

I shutdown my computer every day, so `TickCount` should be much less than one day, right? But when I run this just after starting my computer:

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount).Dump();
```

I get the following result:

```
23.12:11:58.6490000
```

23 days! This is obviously wrong...

BTW, this value is consistent with the value before shutting down the computer, which proves that the value wasn't reset. Note that I didn't use standby or hibernate mode, I really shut down the computer.

**Why is this happening? Isn't the `TickCount` supposed to be reset to 0 after a restart?**

The question is purely academic, as I don't actually need to use `TickCount` in a real project, but I'd like to know why the behavior is completely different from what the doc says...

EDIT: I checked today on my PC at work, and it has the same issue as my home PC: `TickCount` reports that the computer has been running for 19 days, even though I turned it on this morning...

Comment: I've been noticing over the past several years that BIOS power management has been getting progressively buggy.  All of the machines I own have *something* wrong with it.  That machine might not be shutting down the way you think it is.

Comment: What is .Dump() doing?  May want to try .ToString() instead to confirm your results.  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount).ToString works correctly on my machine.

Comment: @Brad, Dump is an extension method available in LinqPad. It just displays the value in the result view (in the case of TimeSpan, it just prints the result of ToString)

Comment: Same issue here. I guess the NSA needed our microphones functional some extra time, so someone in the hardware business decided to give a helping hand... Today I have installed some updates and I restarted it, and THEN it got reset correctly. So, something fishy is going on here... Windows seems involved in the process too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this problem on my laptop, and it was caused by not physically unplugging the power supply from the computer after shutting down. Unless you actually turned the computer off at the wall, I would suspect that a setting is being retained somewhere as long as the computer physically has power to it.